# Automatically fill in form fields in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Lets say you had a simple form to create a new article object in your application.

```
<% form_for @article do |f| %>
<p>
  name:<br />
  <%= f.text_field :name  %>
</p>
<p>
  link:<br />
  <%= f.text_field :link %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= submit_tag %>
</p>
```

I'm using the RSS feed parser Feedtools to get the article names but I can't seem to automatically fill in the form fields from data that is accessible elsewhere. Say the name of the article is accessible through `params[:name]`. How could I get the name of the article from `params[:name]` (or `params[:link]` for that matter) into the form field without the user having to type it in? I don't want to automatically create an article object either because the user may want to modify the name slightly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you pass the information you want to display to the `Article` constructor in the `new` action, the form will render populated. Even though a new object has been instantiated, it will not be persisted to the db because at no point has the save method been called on it. That will happen in the create action.

```
def new
  @article = Article.new :name => "Steve Graham's insane blog", :link => "http://swaggadocio.com/"

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @post }
  end
end
```

Without knowing more about your app logic, I can't offer anymore help on how to stitch the parts together. This should get you nearly there though.

Comment: I'd venture this is the more "standard" way of doing it, since you are using an @article object this lets you reuse the form partial for new and edit.